# enable clear type and font smoothing windows xp

Tags: windows, cleartype

I need to take the screenshot of a webpage with both cleartype and font-smoothing in Windows XP. I know how to enable disable cleartype nor do I enable font smoothing.

Basically what is the difference between two with respect to XP.

Answer (score 2):

ClearType is a form of font smoothing.  In XP you have the following options:

- No font smoothing.
- Standard font smoothing.
- ClearType font smoothing.

The default setting is standard font smoothing. In Vista/7 the default setting is ClearType.

If you know how to enable/disable ClearType then you have already found the dialog which allows to to choose between the three options.

The dialog is presented as a switch to enable or disable font smoothing. If you choose to enable it then you get to make a further choice as to which smoothing method you use: standard or ClearType.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx) tuner on the Microsoft site.